# QTreeWidget sub classing, stop drop indicator from showing given unwanted dropIndicatorPosition

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have the following problem.   I need to stop the drop indicator from showing up when I don't want to complete the drop event, which is conditional on dropIndicatorPosition() returning either `QAbstractItemView::BelowItem` or `QAbstractItemView::AboveItem`.  Right now I subclass `QTreeWidget` and have the following implementation of `dropEvent`.

```
void SubClassedQTreeWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) {
    DropIndicatorPosition position = dropIndicatorPosition();
    if( position != QAbstractItemView::BelowItem && position != QAbstractItemView::AboveItem ){
        // exit since we don't care for other types of drop events
        return;
    }
    QTreeWidget::dropEvent(event);
}
```

I wanted to do this in order to stop visual indication that any drop can happen from showing up.  I only want inbetween black lines to show up.  I've tried re-implementing `dragMoveEvent`, however setting the drop indicator dynamically via:

```
DropIndicatorPosition position = dropIndicatorPosition();
setDropIndicatorShown(!(position != QAbstractItemView::BelowItem && position != QAbstractItemView::AboveItem));
```

doesn't actually do anything, and I would expect some way to not have to perform logic at every drag any way.

Comment: Is the [`showDropIndicator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#showDropIndicator-prop) property what you're looking for?  Just set it to `true` or `false` according to the deop indicator position.

Comment: @G.M. Make sure to read the entire post, `setDropIndicatorPosition` does this, and as you can see, it doesn't work inside of `dragMoveEvent`. I should specify that it will either not do anything or turn off all drop indicators regrardless of logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I catch what you want. My previous answer is suitable for lists only.

To prevent painting boxes around folders you can use something like this:

```
void TreeView::paintEvent( QPaintEvent * event )
{
    DropIndicatorPosition position = dropIndicatorPosition();
    setDropIndicatorShown( position == QAbstractItemView::BelowItem || position == QAbstractItemView::AboveItem );
    base_t::paintEvent( event );
    setDropIndicatorShown( true );
}
```

And to prevent dropping on them (and paint a forbidden cursor while over them):

```
void TreeView::dragMoveEvent( QDragMoveEvent * event )
{
    base_t::dragMoveEvent( event );
    DropIndicatorPosition position = dropIndicatorPosition();
    if ( position != QAbstractItemView::BelowItem && position != QAbstractItemView::AboveItem ) {
        event->ignore();
    }
}
```

But I don't understand why you need that weird thing.

Comment: This doesn't work with DragMoveEvent (that is what I used previously to attempt this) but the paint event thing works.

Comment: If you use paint event only then boxes around folders will not be drawn but you still can drop items on it. To prevent it use drag move event in addition.

Comment: I had already solved that issue before I even posted this question, you don't want to use drag move event for that for performance reasons, you want to use `dropEvent`

Answer (score 0):

You should override `QAbstractItemModel::flags` and add `Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled` flag to the items that can be used as a drop target.

Comment: none of the items can be a drop target... that isn't a reorder. I specifically only want to the drop indicator to be shown when placing in between widgets (only above or below).  Your solution doesn't help with that at all.

Comment: if you have just a list and want to insert new items only between existing ones you can write something like this `return index.isValid() ? Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled : Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;` in your overloaded `QAbstractItemModel::flags` method

Comment: `QTreeWidget` doesn't inherit from `QAbstractItemModel`, so you can't use that function.